# Failed to publish bundle on internal app sharing in google play console

Tags: flutter, bundle, google-play-console

I uploaded my app on the internal test track on google play console ,it took over 2 days and still pending then I decided to upload it to the internal app sharing which brought me this message.

[image: The error]

I've released it as a signed bundle .

As I understood from [the play console help](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9303479?hl=en)

> Uploaded artifacts for internal app sharing aren't shown in your
> artifact library, nor can they be included in releases on testing or
> production tracks.

So this means I should just wait till internal test is published first or I have to build a new unsigned bundle for app sharing ?.

If so .I've read that the internal app sharing has its own signing and I've been using flutter which has a long process of [signing](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android) .So am not sure whether to remove all the code in gradle and the `key.properties` file or generate a new new keystore.

Simiar [issue](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/c9bry3/google_play_consoles_internal_app_sharing/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your app needs to published on a track before it can be uploaded to internal app sharing.

It looks like you are still waiting for your app to be approved on the internal test track, so there is nothing you can do until then, you have to wait that your app is approved and published (and probably avoid publishing another version in the meantime which might reset your waiting time). Since COVID, waiting times have increased, so it will require some patience.

Regarding siging:

- On any track, the app bundle needs to be signed.
- On internal app sharing, the app bundle does *not* need to be signed. So you can remove the signature step in Flutter when building for internal app sharing if that significantly speeds up build times.

Comment: Thanks ,so to remove signing in flutter I should remove all the code in gradle and the `key.properties` file then run `flutter build appbundle`.Or is there a better method?.

Comment: See https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#configure-signing-in-gradle for instructions. Make sure you only disable signing for your debug build, you will still need to sign your app bundle when building release builds for uploads to tracks.